# error: function previously declared with an explicit exception specification redeclared with an implicit exception specification

Tags: android

> system/keymaster/include/keymaster/new:29:6: error: function previously declared with an explicit exception specification redeclared with an implicit exception specification [-Werror,-Wimplicit-exception-spec-mismatch]
>
> void operator delete(void* ptr);
>
> ```
> ^
> ```
>
> system/keymaster/include/keymaster/new:30:6: error: function previously declared with an explicit exception specification redeclared with an implicit exception specification [-Werror,-Wimplicit-exception-spec-mismatch]
>
> void operator delete[](void* ptr)
>
> ```
> ^
> ```
>
> 2 error generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
system/keymaster/include/keymaster/new:29:6: error: function previously declared with an explicit exception specification redeclared with an implicit exception specification [-Werror,-Wimplicit-exception-spec-mismatch]
void operator delete(void* ptr);
     ^
system/keymaster/include/keymaster/new:30:6: error: function previously declared with an explicit exception specification redeclared with an implicit exception specification [-Werror,-Wimplicit-exception-spec-mismatch]
void operator delete[](void* ptr)
     ^
2 error generated.

path: /system/keymaster/include/keymaster/new

void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept;
void operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept;

path: /system/keymaster/keymaster_stl.cpp

void __attribute__((weak)) operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept {
    if (ptr)
        free(ptr);
}

void __attribute__((weak)) operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept {
    if (ptr)
        free(ptr);
}
```